# Why is $map( \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) \neq \{(2y-1, y)| y \in \mathbb Z\} $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$map( \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z) \neq \{(2y-1, y)| y \in \mathbb Z\} $

**Question**: Why the given set not a function of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$?

Some checks for the values show that every image of $\mathbb Z$ is mapped to another image of $\mathbb Z$. So it should be valid in my opinion.

$$-2: 2 \cdot (-2) -1 = -5 $$
$$-1: 2 \cdot (-1) -1 = -3 $$
$$0: 2 \cdot 0 - 1 = -1 $$
$$1: 2 \cdot 1 - 1 = 1 $$
$$2: 2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 3 $$
$$3: 2 \cdot 3 - 1 = 5 $$
$$4: 2 \cdot 4 - 1 = 7 $$

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense: some combination of missing details, nonstandard shorthand, or sloppy notation, I think. Is your question why the given set is not the graph of a function $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Hurkyl : Yes, this is my question. I have updated my question and replaced the equals symbol with an not equals symbol

Comment: Your phrasing is still very unusual. There are no "functions of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$" involved here. Also, "map(Z,Z) = ..." is not how you write "... is a function from Z to Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses the following question:

> Why is the set S = $\{ (2y-1, y) \mid y \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ not the graph of a function from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

The usual convention for the graph of a function is that it is the set of $(\text{input}, \text{output})$ pairs. Among the requirements for such a set to be the graph of a function is:

- For each element $x$ of the domain, there is an ordered pair whose first entry is $x$.

This set does not have this property. For example, there is no ordered pair in $S$ whose first entry is $2$; in fact, every ordered pair in $S$ has an *odd* first entry.